# User model not found in trait

Tags: php, laravel

I have made an API and a trait with a function to handle responses.

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Diseases;
use App\Models\Examinations;
use App\Models\Rec_Doc;
use App\Http\Resources\failter;

trait ApiTraits
{
    public function apiGet($id = null, $table)
    {
        if ($table::find($id)) {
            $status = '200';
            $message = 'ok';
            $data = new failter($table::find($id));
        } elseif ($id === null) {
            $data = failter::collection($table::get());
            $status = '303';
            $message = 'getting all data';
        } else {
            $data = null;
            $status = '404';
            $message = 'not found';
        }
        
        $array = [
            'data' => $data,
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
        ];
        
        return $array;
    }
}
```

After that, in the controller, I use this function:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->apiGet('','User');
}
```

The expected scenario is getting =>

```
$data = failter::collection($table::get());
$status = '303';
$message = 'getting all data';
```

Getting error =>

> Class "User" not found

But I already added a User model.

Comment: that class isn't named `User` it is `App\Models\User` ... it isn't defined in the root namespace

Comment: I has to be a fully qualified classname as @lagbox suggested. When you reference a classname by a string, you must always use a fully-qualified namespace. You can prepend `App\\Models\\` (note the double slashes) to `$table` when looking it up inside the trait.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just defining the model name (User), you can try defining it with full namespaces;  `App\Models\User` or `User::class`.

Answer (score 0):

The class isn't called `User` it's actually called `\App\Models\User`. When you put `use App\Models\User` at the top of your file, it installs a shorthand for that file where every time you refer to the bareword `User` what you *actually* mean is `\App\Models\User`. Strings (e.g. `$cls='Foo';new $cls;`) do not get the same treatment.

Try using the `::class` notation in the controller:

```php
// This line is required at the top of the file as well.
use App\Models\User;

public function users()
{
    return $this->apiGet('', User::class);
    // Meaning the same thing as:
    return $this->apiGet('', '\App\Models\User');
    // And the same thing as:
    return $this->apiGet('', \App\Models\User::class);
}
```

`::class` makes the bareword into a string with the fully qualified class name.

Using `::class` instead of the stringified class name is a good habit to get into because it makes refactoring easier, and the code is easier to read too, since `User::class` is clear that it's a class name, whereas `'User'` (string) could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the full path to the class `App\Models\User`

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->apiGet('',User::class);
}
```

```php
public function apiGet($id = null, $className)
{
    if (!class_exists($className)) {
        throw new LogicException("Unable to load class: $className");
    }

    $query = $className::query();

    if ($query->find($id)) { ...
```